# Freescale: Why is the Bit Rate( and file size) for H264 encoded videos on Freescale iMX6 inversely proportional to the resolution of video?

Tags: h.264, codec, imx6

I am trying to build a live video streaming embedded server on Freescale imx6 with Gstreamer and h264 codecs. The client(Linux PC) is connected via a wireless link that streams the video transmitted by the server.

Recently I performed some test to measure the average bitrate for a h264 encoded file on a Freescale imx6 processor. I used the GStreamer element 'testvideosrc', ran it for 60 seconds and encoded it using the gstreamer-imx plugins that utilizes the hardware encoder (h264) and saved the file, and calculated the bitrate. 
Following is the command :

```
timeout --signal=SIGINT 60s \
gst-launch-1.0 -ev videotestsrc pattern=18 ! \
video/x-raw,width=100,height=50,framerate=10/1 ! \
imxvpuenc_h264 bitrate=5 ! h264parse ! \
filesink location=60s.h264 && \
    echo $(( $(stat --format=%s 60s.h264) / 60 * 8))
```

The test was performed at 10 fps for different resolutions, and the bitrates are as follows:

```
Resolution                                              BitRate
 100 x 50                                               ~120.3K
 320 x 240                                              ~93.7K
 640 x 480                                              ~52.7K
 1280 x 960                                             ~32.3K
```

I am trying to understand the behaviour of the H264 encoder, as to why the bitrate is inversely proportional to the increasing resolution sizes. I had hoped that with increasing resolutions, the bitrate will also increase and hence was opting for a lower resolution image, for streaming through the wireless link. 
Can anyone explain, why this behaviour exists with the h264 codedc? Or am I at fault in understanding the bitrate demand.

Comment: What frame rate do you get at each resolution?

Comment: the test was performed at a constant frame rate of 10 fps. [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50945/freescale-why-is-the-bit-rate-and-file-size-for-h264-encoded-videos-on-freesc) the problem is explained in more detail.